# What software should I use to create a HPC (High performance compute) cluster with CentOS 6.5 VMs locally?

Tags: linux, centos, cluster

I've read about Torque, Slurm resource managers and Maui, Open Grid scheduler, Sonf of Grid Engine but I do not know which is more appropriate to use in a local environment? I've also read that I need to use a MPI library. I already have a cluster implemented with Conga but can I use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use prebuild Linux distribution named www.rocksclusters.org  As I know it is Redhat based. Rockclusters consist of lots of cluster file systems, mpis, job schedulers.

If you want to install yourself:
For shared file system, there are many alternatives, you can use GFS2.
For MPI, there are many alternatives, you can use openmpi.
For scheduler, there are many alternatives, you can use torque.